# Thought Experiment: spinning ping-pong ball with forward motion on International Space Station. What would Happen?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, aerodynamics

Forward moving ping-pong ball with a with a certain rotation/spin in zero G, 1 atmosphere. Would magnus effect cause Fibonacci spiral?

If you did this experiment in a space station would the ball 'orbit in a circular fashion. The ball would have to be spinning at several thousand rpm though.

I’m assuming it would decay into an inward spiraling orbit, similar to a Fibonacci spiral. But it will lose most of the angular momentum, before it loses all of its forward momentum so path would start to straighten and spiral back out into a straight line.

Comment: No. If the ball's centre of mass were at the "mechanical" centre, the centre would be stand still - if not, the ball would wobble a bit as it rotated around its centre of mass, which would stand still. There is no centrally-directed force on it to make it move in a circular path. The only forces on it - drag from its spinning in the air - would act tangentially on the ball to oppose its spin. If the ball were perfectly round, these forces would sum to nought at all times.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, I think the question could be rephrased as "Can you throw a curveball in zero g?". My thinking is that this is asking if the ball is traveling with a certain velocity ("vector"), i.e., what is the aerodynamic effect.

Comment: @lionelbrits Yes, that makes more sense. Declan, if Lionel's interpretation is right, could you please change your question to make this clearer?

Comment: If you're asking whether the [Magnus Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) works in the ISS, then yes it does.

Comment: The current text of the question implies that the ball is at rest with respect to the air around it, in which case the Magnus effect is inapplicable. If you're thinking of a configuration where the ball starts in motion with respect to the ISS you should specify that in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The motion of an object's center of mass is only affected by external forces, so if there were no significant differences in the external forces the spin shouldn't affect the path, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147837/59406)). But you clarified that you were asking about curveballs, and those are explained in terms of the fact that the spin of the ball changes the external force from the air on the ball, so I think this should still work in zero G. As explained [here](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/211_fall2002.web.dir/jon_drobnis/Curveball.html), the spin's interaction with the airflow creates different pressure on different sides of the ball, leading to a net [Magnus force](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node43.html) at a right angle to the ball's velocity. Since circular orbits are possible in any situation where the net force is always perpendicular to the direction of motion, it would be possible for the ball to orbit in a circle if the magnus force were the only force acting on it as it traveled, but there is also a drag force which is pointing in the opposite direction to the motion, so I think realistically you would have something more like a [decaying orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay) spiraling inward. If anyone wants to do some calculations of the relative magnitude of the drag and Magnus forces, equations can be found [here](http://spiff.rit.edu/richmond/baseball/traj/traj.html) along with realistic values for various parameters in the case of a baseball (not a ping-pong ball).

Comment: Since there is drag, the tangential velocity would decrease, as well as the ball's spin. I don't think the curvature would change.

Comment: @LDC3 - What do you mean by "I don't think the curvature would change"? Are you disagreeing that it would behave similarly to a satellite experiencing atmospheric drag, spiralling in with a decaying orbit of decreasing radius? (the initial radius would depend on the initial spin and velocity relative to the air, it would satisfy F = mv^2/r where F is the magnitude of the Magnus force given that spin and velocity)

Comment: I don't think that the ball would spiral inward. The lateral force decreases as the velocity and spin decrease. The maximum lateral force occurs when the ball leaves the hand and decreases with time. A likely result would be that the ball circles, without changing the radius of curvature.

Comment: @LDC3 - By "lateral" do you mean the radial or the tangential force? If the tangential, that also happens for satellites with decaying orbits due to atmospheric drag. If the radial Magnus force, is there any reason to think F would decrease in exactly the same way v^2 was decreasing, so that the orbital radius would remain unchanged? Also, are you sure it's correct that for spinning balls, the airflow produces a torque that decreases the rate of spin?

Comment: I mean the Magnus force. Yes, the air that surrounds the ball needs to get it's energy from somewhere, which would be the spinning ball. Therefore the spin on the ball must decrease since the air rotates with the ball, and causes the Magnus force. The Magnus force requires an input of energy in order for it to be continuous. Since we know that drag causes the velocity to decrease, the energy for the Magnus force must come from the spin.

Comment: @LDC3 - Yes, that makes sense. What about my other point that F would have to decrease in exact proportion to v^2 in order for the radius of curvature to be constant?

Comment: I said it was a likely outcome, it could possibly increase in radius, or decrease (like you predict). I'm not able to do the calculations necessary to determine the correct outcome. Also, one necessary quantity that has yet to be specified is the mass of the ball to determine the rate of change in angular momentum.